# emit eventHub inside vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

im wondering how can i use `this.$eventHub.$emit('something');`

But inside of vuex

the reason why i need this is because im using a plugin (vuex-persist-indexeddb), and there is a method called rehydrated (which fires when the db is loaded) so i want to emit an event on eventHub for warn the db is loaded...

i made the eventHub like this in the main.js file:

`Vue.prototype.$eventHub = new Vue(); // Global event bus`

In my store/index.js file ive loaded Vue but it doesnt recognize the $eventHub called from Vue.$eventHub...

imported with:
`import Vue from "vue";`

Hope anyone can help me, thanks in advice

Answer (score 0):

i've already solved it :)
the solution was create a new folder/file like this:

folder: eventHub/index.js

file contents:

```
import Vue from "vue";
const eventBus = new Vue()
export default eventBus
```

and then in the router file simple import and use

```
import eventHub from '@/eventHub'

eventHub.$emit('something');
```

pulled from the official docs:
[vue docs events](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html#_2-x-syntax)